# Defining a None matrix in python through different methods obtains different results

Tags: python, matrix, initialization, memoization

I have the following python code,

```
def helper(nums, d, n, memo):
    if d == 0:
        return True
    if (d < 0 or n == 0):
        return False
    if memo[n][d] is not None:
        return memo[n][d]
    res = helper(nums, (d - nums[n - 1]), (n - 1), memo) or helper(nums, d, (n - 1), memo)
    memo[n][d] = res
    return res


def solution(nums):    
    sum_nums = sum(nums)
    if sum_nums % 2 != 0:
        return False
    d = sum_nums // 2
    n = len(nums)
    # Initialization
    memo = [[None] * (d + 1) for _ in range(n + 1)]
    return  helper(nums, d, (n - 1), memo)
```

For the input `nums = [3, 4, 7, 4, 15, 18, 14, 14, 17]`, solution(nums) returns `True`. However, if I replace memo initialization in `solution` (i.e., the line `memo = [[None] * (d + 1) for _ in range(n + 1)]`), with the following initialization,
`memo = [[None] * (d + 1)] * (n + 1)`
solution(nums) returns `False` (with the same nums). I was wondering if anyone can help me to understand the reason for such different results, because it appears to me that both initialization methods are the same.

FYI the above code is a solution to the "Partition Equal Subset Sum" problem that uses memoization (leetcode link is https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-equal-subset-sum/description/)

```
def solution(nums):    
    sum_nums = sum(nums)
    if sum_nums % 2 != 0:
        return False
    d = sum_nums // 2
    n = len(nums)
    # Initialization 1
    memo = [[None] * (d + 1) for _ in range(n + 1)]
    return  helper(nums, d, (n - 1), memo)
```

`nums = [3, 4, 7, 4, 15, 18, 14, 14, 17]`
`solution(nums)` --> True

Whereas (memo initialization line has been changed),

```
def solution(nums):    
    sum_nums = sum(nums)
    if sum_nums % 2 != 0:
        return False
    d = sum_nums // 2
    n = len(nums)
    # Initialization 2
    memo = [[None] * (d + 1)] * (n + 1)
    return  helper(nums, d, (n - 1), memo)
```

`nums = [3, 4, 7, 4, 15, 18, 14, 14, 17]`
`solution(nums)` --> False (expected True)

Comment: TLDR: `[[None] * (d + 1)] * (n + 1)` - you have `n + 1` references to the same `list`-object.

Comment: Thank you so much Dmitry. That referencing was the root cause of the wrong answer.